# PHP email script - how can i have a variable number of arguments passed in?

Tags: php

I have an ajax post coming to my PHP  file for sending an email.
The issue is, my html contact form is always changing, one user might use 10 text-inputs, another user might use 5, etc.

The data is coming to the PHP file like this :

```
txt1=John&txt2=aol@aol.com&txt3=5550123944&dropDown1=Sales&question=How+are+you
```

The PHP file is like this :

```
<?php
$emailSubject = 'Customer Has a Question!';
$webMaster = 'giberisk@yahoo.com';

$name = $_POST ['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST ['phone'];
$question = $_POST ['question'];


$body = <<<EOD
<br><hr><br>
Name: $name <br>
Email: $email <br>
Phone: $phone <br>
Question: $question <br>
EOD;
$headers = "From: $email\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";
$success = mail($webMaster, $emailSubject, $body, $headers);
$theResults = <<<EOD
EOD;
echo "$theResults";
?>
```

What do I have to do, so that the PHP file finds out how many arguments were passed, and to name the variables after the name of those arguments ?

I hope I was clear enough,

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can loop through the arguments... With a `foreach` type of statement looping over the _POST array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could do foreach, like

```
$count = count($_POST); //shows number of variables POST'ed
foreach($_POST as $key => $val ) {
   echo $key . "==>" .$val;   
   //or assign values to key variables
   ${$key} = $value; //${$key} will be variable holding $value as value
}
```

Comment: can you please show me how can I integrate your code in my script? I am more of a javascript guy, and PHP looks very strange from where I stand now.